# Why am I still receving this error even if i have imported * from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import StringVar
root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x400')

l2 = Label(root, text = 'USERNAME')
l3 = Label (root, text = 'PASSWORD')

l2.grid()
l3.grid(row=1)

user = Tk.SringVar()
password = Tk.StringVar()

e1 = Entry (root, textvariable=user)
e2 = Entry (root, textvariable=password)

e1.grid()
e2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   user = Tk.SringVar()
>   AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'SringVar'

fixing this gives:

> user = Tk.StringVar()
>   AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'StringVar'

Comment: What error are you referring to?

Comment: You haven't said what the error is, but it probably doesn't help that you wrote `SringVar` instead of `StringVar`

Comment: `StringVar` is defined in `tkinter` and not in `tkinter.Tk`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing `*` but still calling Tk.

```
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import StringVar
root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x400')

l2 = Label(root, text = 'USERNAME')
l3 = Label (root, text = 'PASSWORD')

l2.grid()
l3.grid(row=1)

user = StringVar() #Typo here #Not
password = StringVar()

e1 = Entry (root, textvariable=user)
e2 = Entry (root, textvariable=password)

e1.grid()
e2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I tested this code and it should be running fine now. When importing `*` it imports all functions and objects so there was no reason to call `Tk.StringVar()`.